# Computation of $\phi\phi^T$ where $\phi$ is a vector that depends on semi-orthogonal matrices.

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, svd

Let $r \leq \min(m,n)$ and $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$, $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ be matrices such that $U^TU=V^TV=I_r$.  Let also $U_{\perp} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (m-r)}$ and $V_{\perp} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n-r)}$ be two matrices such that $ \begin{bmatrix}
U & U_{\perp} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $ \begin{bmatrix}
V & V_{\perp} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ are orthogonal matrices.

For every $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$, let  $$\phi(i,j)=\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{vec}(U_iV_j^T) \\ \operatorname{vec}(U_iV_{\perp,j}^T)
 \\ \operatorname{vec}(U_{\perp,i}V_j^T)
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, $$where $d:=r(m+n)-r^2$, $A_i$ is the vector equal to the (transposed) $i$-th row of the matrix $A$ and $\operatorname{vec}$ is the [vectorization operation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))

**I am wondering wether or not we have** $$B:=\sum_{1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n}\phi(i,j)\phi(i,j)^T=I_d.$$
*I can show that it is true* for $m=n=2$ and $r=1$. Indeed, in this case, $U_i$, $U_{\perp,i}$, $V_j$ and $V_{\perp,j}$ are just scalars ; the terms in the diagonal of $B$ are $\sum_{i}U_i^2\sum_{j}V_j^2$, $\sum_{i}U_i^2\sum_{j}V_{\perp,j}^2$ and $\sum_{i}U_{\perp,i}^2\sum_{j}V_j^2$, which are all equal to $1$ because of the orthogonality property. Finally, the terms outside the diagonal will either have $\sum_{i}U_{i}U_{\perp,i}$ or $\sum_{j} V_jV_{\perp,j}$ as a factor, which are equal to $0$ because $U$,$U_{\perp}$ (resp $V$,$V_{\perp}$) are columns of the orthogonal matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}
U & U_{\perp} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ (resp. $ \begin{bmatrix}
V & V_{\perp} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ ).

I am struggling to handle the general case because I can't find a clean way to express $\phi(i,j)\phi(i,j)^T.$
If the above equality happens to be false in general, I would still be interested in the invertibility of $B$, and its minimal eigenvalue (I would really like to have $\lambda_{\min}(B) \geq 1$).

Comment: I have managed to prove it by explicitly writing out each term in the vector product (the diagonal terms involve the norm of the orthogonal columns, the other terms involve scalar products of these columns, that are 0). I'd still be interested in a more elegant proof though.